Jquery each SVG element
Here is my problem: I use the Wordpress image map pro plugin to generate plans with clickable areas in SVG. When the page loads, the HTML code is generated. I want to loop in jquery on the SVG elements generated by the plugin in order to be able to retrieve their data-title that I must use later. But it does not find me any occurrence. On the other hand, if I tell it to loop as soon as I click on an area, it retrieves all the elements. I do not understand. I notice that the plugin's JS file is loaded at the end. By creating a JS file that loads after the plugin's, it does not work.
website url : https://preprod.meriadeck.com/liste-boutiques-meriadeck/
code not working :
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery( ".imp-objects" ).each(function() {
            let valueObjectMapSingleProduct = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
            console.log("toto");
        });
    });

code working :
 jQuery('.liste-boutique-nav li').click(function(){
        jQuery( ".imp-objects" ).each(function() {
            let valueObjectMapSingleProduct = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
            console.log("toto");
        });

    });

I tried to load the code in the footer after calling the plugin's js file.
When trying to use the each loop on SVG elements independent of the plugin, everything works but as soon as it comes to SVG elements generated by the plugin, it doesn't work. I have the impression that an action (click for example) is needed for it to work.

You do not need a "user-action" per se, you need an "event" that tells you wenn the plugin has finished creating the clickable areas. The plugin's docs describe the API of the plugin which seems to have a way to .subscribe to it's "actions" (look for the "JavaScript Hooks" section, I'd guess that the action type you want is "mapInit") with callbacks - run your code inside such callback.

Please see [ask], then write a post title question as though we're human and not a search bot. Also take the [tour].

Protip: Use jQuery(function($) { ... }) instead of your document ready statement to shorten it up and also let you do $() instead of jQuery() inside it.
